# How to avoid select file window when refreshing link

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a select file window popping up while updating a link to an excel file. I believe it's caused by the destination file being saved at the moment I refresh the link.

I have 2 computers. I open file "A" on the first one and file "B" on the other.

File "A" runs this macro:

```
application.enableevents = false
Do until(I set loop for couple minutes )
Range("a1").value = 1
save
range("a1).value = 2
save
Loop
```

File B runs this macro:

```
range("b2").value = (link to File A, cell "a1")
z = 1
do until (runs for couple minutes)
Cells(z,1).value = range("b2").value
z = z+1
loop
```

So basically the first file continuously changes the value of cell "a1" between 1 and 2, and saves each time, while the second one constantly refreshes the link and records the linked cell value.

It works for a few rounds, then a select file window pops up.

Exact formula for the cell containing link:

```
"='[" & BAZAO.Name & "]" & "ZMIANY'" & "!a1"
```

And in excel cell it looks like that:
„='[BWP 215.xlsm]ZMIANY'!a1”

The line of code that refreshes the link:

```
BAZA.UpdateLink (BAZAZ.Range("C3").Value)
```

BAZA - name of FILE B
BAZAZ.range("c3").value - contains address and name of file A

```
Range("b2").value  = "='[" & BAZAO.Name & "]" & "ZMIANY'" & "!a1"
„='[BWP 215.xlsm]ZMIANY'!a1”
```

Can anyone tell me how to suppress this select file window, or if there is any other workaround?

I think it's happening because when opening the excel file, excel creates it's copy with generated name. When changes are being saved and the original file replaced, excel deletes original file first, and then puts a temporary file in its place changing name to the original one.
I guess the select file window pops up when my macros hit between that moments.
Is this the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a workaround.
Instead of using a cell to track file avaliability I have made the code to create file "inuse.txt" in the "file A" directory whenever its in use.
Then the "file B" just checks if that file is present through dir command